# Обход капчи при регистрации

Tags: javascript, php

Есть такая ситуация: на некотором сайте  нужно зарегистрироваться на шенген визу, но время и дата, когда появляются свободные места, нигде не указывается, то есть нужно сидеть с утра до вечера 5 дней в неделю и мониторить каждую минуту, нет ли мест. На сайте присутствует капча (как бы для отрезания бот программ), но когда появляются места, буквально за 2 мин. они пропадают (для статистики за эти две минути разбирают около 300 мест).
Как вы думаете, это дело простых людей, которые хотят зарегистрироватся, или стоит какой-нибудь скрипт и мониторит постоянно наличие свободных мест и сам их занимает, чтобы обычным людям нельзя было просто зарегистрироватся?

Comment: @Helios, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Часть (0%-20%) это реальные люди, а остальное охватывают боты (скрипты). 
Вы даже если попадете на страницу регистрации, пока заполните все данные, то уже свободных мест не останется, и вас попросят зайти позже.

Ищите в Интернете ресурсы, которые предлагаю услуги регистрации (вот они как раз и являются владельцами этих ботов).

Либо напишите свой скрипт регистрации. :)

Comment: Но там же стоит капча, для отрезания таких ботов, или она не эффективна?? И можно ли действительно создать скрипт который будет делать регистрацию, и не будет он забанен админами сайта, если они конечно не в зговоре с  теме кто сейчас ворует места?

Comment: Хочу уточнить вопрос, видны ли админам сайта, ети боты, и могут ли они их высилять и отсекать?

Comment: Их никак не вычислить!
Таких ботов по ip не забанишь. Так как они работают через proxy.
А что касается капчи, то:
1. Если капча простая, то ее можно легко распознать. Уже есть куча(бесплатных) готовых сервисов.
2. Если капча сложная, то тут нанимают индусов, которые за 1-3 рубля тебе в ручном режиме распознают капчу. И время распознавания таким способом до 30 секунд. А если купить премиум аккаунт, то время до 15 сек.

Comment: я вообще сомневаюсь, что это нормальный сайт. @Helios возьмите шенген в какой-нибудь другой - более дружелюбной стране.